# Cannot run my JMeter webdriver sampler script via command prompt

Tags: javascript, jmeter, webdriver, performance-testing

When I try to run my JMeter WebDriver sampler script via command prompt, the error below shows up. Is there any solution for this?

```
F:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\TestScriptRecorder.jmx is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to execute .jmx file directly, it won't work this way, you need to launch `jmeter.bat` file and pass the .jmx file via `-t` command-line argument like:

```
F:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t F:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\TestScriptRecorder.jmx -l result.jtl
```

or

```
java -jar F:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t F:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\ -l result.jtl
```

References:

- [Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Comment: How could I pause my jmeter script for few seconds (between 2 actions)    var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10000)  it doesn't works for me

Comment: Use `java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000)` as the alternative. See [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) and [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guides for more details.

Comment: You are a Legend. Please keep helping us :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want run your Jmx through command line follow the below steps.

1. Open command prompt
2. go to the path of where your jmeter.bat or jmete.sh file is placed(ex: C:\Users\ABC\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin)
3. Write the command as below

For Windows:           `jmeter -n -t C:\your_testScript_path\yourscript.jmx`

For ubuntu/linux:     `./jmeter.sh -n -t C:\your_testScript_path\yourscript.jmx`

you  can aslo pass any values to the jmx files using command line using command line paremeters like `-JUsers=10` where in it should be defined in jmx like `${__P(Users,1)}`